# Media won't upload on Wordpress via EC2 instance

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have install Wordpress have it all working on an EC2 instance and RDS.

One small problem I am having is uploading images through the media/image uploader on the wp-admin it keeps saying the following:

'“FC1.jpeg” has failed to upload due to an error
The uploaded file could not be moved to /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2012/06.'

I think it's most likely the permissions of the folder, because I used it yesterday and it worked, but after i sort of messed around with the chmod command on ssh.

I know the wp-content folder should be 775 and I have tried that but it doesn't work.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The permissions you used gave full privileges to the owner so they should work.  Check to see who the owner and group are (ls -l on a *nix system).

You will need to know the webserver user and group. Check with your sysadmin (or in /etc/passwd).  On *nix systems it is often ww-data or apache.

The owner and group should be set to the webserver.  If they are not, run `sudo chown webserverUser:webserverGroup`.

Comment: Well I am on a Amazon Linux 3.2 instance on EC2. I have tried chmodding it to 777 then back to 755 but still now luck.